# How Can I Change Database Columns into Index Rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When generating a scaffold, Ruby on Rails by default creates a new column for each attribute, but how do I change some of those attributes into rows?

I am a beginner to Rails, and coding in general. I've been using Rails extensively the past few months, but I still have a ways to go as demonstrated by the noviceness of the question so please approach this question with gentle hands and a beginner's mind.

I don't even need you to solve the problem, but just give me some clear guidance on where I can put my finger tips next.

I'd like :name & :metric to be a row. For each :quantifieds there are many :results. I'd like the results to stay as a column that falls down the page under its respective quantified.

This is what my table currently looks like:

[image]

But this is how I want it to behave:

With each new quantified added, instead of it showing up at the bottom of the page I want it to show up across, horizontally instead of vertically.

```html
class CreateQuantifieds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quantifieds do |t|
      t.string :categories
      t.string :name
      t.string :metric

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  has_many :results #correct
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'instance') }

 CATEGORIES = ['averaged', 'instance']

end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
end
```

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :name, :metric, :result, :date, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Or do I keep playing around with the index view I've tried all sorts of 's and html tags, but I could never get the code to look like above, which is why I think the answer may lie deeper.

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->

<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

<table>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>     
      <th><%= averaged.name %> (<%= averaged.metric %>)</th>
      <td><% averaged.results.each do |result| %>
        <tr><td><%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %></td>
        <td><%= result.result_value %></td></tr>
    <% end %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>INSTANCE</b></h4></div>

<table>
  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
    <% if instance.user == current_user %>     
      <th><%= instance.name %> (<%= instance.metric %>)</th>
      <td><% instance.results.each do |instance| %>
        <tr><td><%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %></td>
        <td><%= result.result_value %></td></tr>
    <% end %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>

  <div class="values-button">
  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Try another tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Dynamic Table: Attributes = Columns, Nested Attributes = Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242403/create-a-dynamic-table-attributes-columns-nested-attributes-rows)

Comment: Could you please stop asking the same question under different titles?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I realized I was asking the wrong question. I had columns and rows backwards.

Comment: @7stud what tutorial?

Comment: Here's a tip: when you copy something, you can't leave out random parts and expect the result to make sense.

Comment: @7stud people get mad at me if I do and people get mad at me if I don't. What did I leave out and I can add it. I try to only add the code that I think might be useful.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli, You are misunderstanding me:  I didn't advocate that you barf your code all over the screen.  But if you construct a question, such as: *I am looking at the color red.  What color am I looking at?* and then you omit certain parts:  *I am looking at.  What am I looking at?*  It doesn't work.  In other words, your question is a bunch of rambling nonsense.

Comment: I'm sorry @7stud my question is a bunch of rambling nonsense, I promise its not from a lack of effort. I've done multiple tutorials and I still don't know where to even start in the code to solve what I thought would be a simple problem. I added more text to the question hopefully it makes it a little more logical. I do appreciate your honesty.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli, In your other question you posted how you want the table to look.  In your opinion, is that the most important part of your question, or is that the least important part of your question?

Comment: @7stud in this question I took out that picture to avoid confusion and focus on a more minute aspect of a larger question. But for this one I just wanted, using the example picture above, for Blog (subscribers) Weight (pounds) Ran (miles) to be horizontally across the page instead of vertically down it. I want the result_date & the result_value to continue to fall under it's respective :name (:metric). Have any ideas on what I can do, read, or way to ask a more clarifying question?